# Sapui5 use my new controle in xml

Tags: controls, sapui5, extends

this is how i create new control:

https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/sdk/#docs/guide/91f0a8dc6f4d1014b6dd926db0e91070.html

```sap
sap.ui.somelib.SomeControl.extend("my.OwnControl", {
       ...
       init: function() {
             if (sap.ui.somelib.SomeControl.prototype.init) { // check whether superclass implements the method
                    sap.ui.somelib.SomeControl.prototype.init.apply(this, arguments); // call the method with the original arguments
             }

             //... do any further initialization of your subclass... 
       }
```

Is possible to use some controle in my xml view ?

Comment: I use notation with dependency injection like:

code(`sap.ui.define([
 "sap/m/ObjectListItem"
], function(ObjectListItem) {
 "use strict";

 return ObjectListItem.extend("my.newListItem", {
`)

and in xml:

code(`<core:View xmlns:my="my">
<custom:SystemStatusListItem title="laptop" intro="{Description}" id="tem1"/> `)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When defining a control like this:
`sap.ui.core.Control.extend("my.Square", ...`

and declaring the XML namespace
`xmlns:my="my"`

you can use your control like this:
`<my:Square text="test" size="100px"/>`

BUT only if you also declare your control as existing module:
`jQuery.sap.declare("my.Square");`
(this last part is missing in the other answer)

Here is a running example with the "Square" control from the documentation:
http://jsbin.com/zuxebev/1/edit?html,output

Comment: BUT not if you are using AMD style syntax right? I mean something like `sap.ui.define(['sap/ui/core/Control'], function (Control) { return Control.extend("my.Square", { ... })});`

Comment: Right... but you can still `jQuery.sap.declare("my.Square");` to make it work. Makes me wonder, though, why this is needed from XMLView perspective.